# Magento: Adding filter to custom report

Tags: magento, zend-framework, report

after creating a own report and adding a custom column called vendor to it I want to filter the results by vendor.

I tried it with `addAttributeToSelect('vendor')` but I got the following error:

> Fatal error: Call to undefined method Mage_Reports_Model_Resource_Report_Collection::addAttributeToSelect()

My grid class:

```
    public function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();
    $this->setId('salesreportsGrid');
    $this->setDefaultSort('created_at');
    $this->setDefaultDir('ASC');
    $this->setSaveParametersInSession(true);
    $this->setSubReportSize(false);
}

protected function _prepareCollection() {
    parent::_prepareCollection();
    $this->getCollection()->addAttributeToSelect('vendor')->initReport('salesreports/salesreports');
    return $this;
}

protected function _prepareColumns() {

    $this->addColumn('sku', array(
        'header'    =>Mage::helper('reports')->__('SKU'),
        'index'     =>'sku'
    ));

    $this->addColumn('name', array(
        'header'    =>Mage::helper('reports')->__('Product Name'),
        'index'     =>'order_items_name'
    ));

    $this->addColumn('vendor', array(
        'header'    =>Mage::helper('reports')->__('Vendor'),
        'index'     =>'vendor',
        'final_index' =>'vendor',
        'type'      =>'options',
        'options'   =>$this->_getAttributeOptions('vendor')
    ));

    $this->addColumn('ordered_qty', array(
        'header'    =>Mage::helper('reports')->__('Quantity Ordered'),
        'width'     =>'120px',
        'align'     =>'right',
        'index'     =>'ordered_qty',
        'total'     =>'sum',
        'type'      =>'number'
    ));

    $this->addColumn('base_cost', array(
        'header'    =>Mage::helper('reports')->__('Cost'),
        'width'     =>'120px',
        'align'     =>'right',
        'index'     =>'base_cost',
        'total'     =>'sum',
        'currency_code' => Mage::app()->getStore()->getCurrentCurrencyCode(),
        'type'      =>'price'
    ));

    $this->addExportType('*/*/exportCsv', Mage::helper('salesreports')->__('CSV'));
    $this->addExportType('*/*/exportXml', Mage::helper('salesreports')->__('XML'));
    return parent::_prepareColumns();
}

public function getRowUrl($row) {
    return false;
}

public function getReport($from, $to) {
    if ($from == '') {
        $from = $this->getFilter('report_from');
    }
    if ($to == '') {
        $to = $this->getFilter('report_to');
    }
    $totalObj = Mage::getModel('reports/totals');
    $totals = $totalObj->countTotals($this, $from, $to);
    $this->setTotals($totals);
    $this->addGrandTotals($totals);
    return $this->getCollection()->getReport($from, $to);
}


protected function _getAttributeOptions($attribute_code)
{
    $attribute = Mage::getModel('eav/config')->getAttribute('catalog_product', $attribute_code);
    $options = array();
    foreach( $attribute->getSource()->getAllOptions(true, true) as $option ) {
        $options[$option['value']] = $option['label'];
    }
    return $options;
}
```

My model class:

```
    function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
    $this->setResourceModel('sales/order_item');
    $this->_init('sales/order_item','item_id');
```

}

```
public function setDateRange($from, $to)
{
        $this->getSelect()->reset()
        ->from(
            array('order_items' => $this->getTable('sales/order_item')),
            array(
                'ordered_qty' => 'order_items.qty_ordered',
                'order_items_name' => 'order_items.name',
                'vendor' => 'attrval.value',
                'base_cost' => '(SUM(order_items.qty_ordered) * order_items.base_cost)',
                'sku' => 'order_items.sku'
            ))
        ->joinLeft(array('p' => 'catalog_product_entity'), 'order_items.product_id = p.entity_id')
        ->joinLeft(array('eav' => 'eav_attribute'), 'p.entity_type_id = eav.entity_type_id')
        ->joinLeft(array('attr' =>'eav_attribute_option'), 'attr.attribute_id = eav.attribute_id')
        ->joinLeft(array('attrval' =>'eav_attribute_option_value'), 'attrval.option_id = attr.option_id')
        ->where("eav.attribute_code='vendor'")
        ->where("order_items.created_at BETWEEN '".$from."' AND '".$to."'")
        ->where('parent_item_id IS NULL')
        ->group('order_items.product_id')
        ->having('SUM(order_items.qty_ordered) > ?', 0)
        ->order(
            array(
                'SUM(order_items.qty_ordered) DESC'
            ));

        #echo $this->getSelect()->__toString();exit;

    return $this;
}

public function setStoreIds($storeIds)
{
    return $this;
}
```

Comment: Is vendor your custom attribute ?

Comment: Yes, vendor is the attribute_code.

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert your report collection to product collection to make the products visible in grid.

```
protected function _prepareCollection() {
    // $this->getCollection()->addAttributeToSelect('vendor')->initReport('salesreports/salesreports');
    $collection = $this->getCollection();
    // store product ids
    $common_ids = array();
    foreach($collection as $item){
        $common_ids[] = $item->getId();
    }
    if(!count($common_ids)){
        $collection = null;
    }else{
        $collection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection')
            ->addFieldToFilter('entity_id', $common_ids)
            ->addAttributeToSelect('*');
    }
    $this->setCollection($collection);
    parent::_prepareCollection();
    return $this;
}
```

Comment: The products are shown in the grid but there is no filter for the vendor attribute. If I use your code I get this error: Call to a member function getReportFull() on a non-object in app/code/core/Mage/Reports/Model/Resource/Report/Collection.php on line 286

Comment: @user3684098 I have not used `getReportFull()` function above.. I am not sure about that error. I updated my post as there were some variable mis-spells.

Comment: BTW, how is it possible to use `$this->getCollection()` in `_prepareCollection` function? Have you set the collection already using `$this->setCollection($yourCollection)`?

Comment: I think that is the problem. I haven't used setCollection(). I get the data by the function setDateRange() as you can see above.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
protected function _prepareCollection()
{
    $collection = $this->getCollection()->addAttributeToSelect('vendor')->initReport('salesreports/salesreports');
    $this->setCollection($collection);
    return parent::_prepareCollection();
}
```

Comment: Hm, then I get this error: Fatal error: Call to undefined method Mage_Reports_Model_Resource_Report_Collection::addAttributeToSelect() in ...